# could not execute query in Hibernate with MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

**DAO**

```
public class TtmpHome {
private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(TtmpHome.class);
// Contexte de persistance
private EntityManagerFactory emf = PersistenceManager.getInstance().getEntityManagerFactory();
private EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();

//staff

public Ttmp findByStationName(Integer stNumber) {
    String queryS = "select t from Ttmp t where t.stationNumber =?1";
    Ttmp t = null;
    try {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(queryS);
        query.setParameter(1, stNumber);
        List eqList = query.getResultList();
        if (eqList != null && eqList.size() > 0)
            t = (Ttmp) eqList.get(0);
        log.debug("get successful");
        return t;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("get failed", re);
    }
}
}
```

**ENTITY**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ttmp", catalog = "semap")
public class Ttmp implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int id;
    private String requestNumber;
    private String requestFrom;
    private Date requestDate;
    private Integer stationNumber;
    private String site;
    private String region;
    private String requestReceiver;
    private String descIssue;
    private String thirdParty;
    private String descResolutionAction;
    private String closerType;
    private Integer closeNum;
    private Date dateAction;
    private String agentAction;
    private String validation;
    private String comment;

    public Ttmp() {
    }

    public Ttmp(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Ttmp(int id, String requestNumber, String requestFrom,
            Date requestDate, Integer stationNumber, String site,
            String region, String requestReceiver, String descIssue,
            String thirdParty, String descResolutionAction, String closerType,
            Integer closeNum, Date dateAction, String agentAction,
            String validation, String comment) {
        this.id = id;
        this.requestNumber = requestNumber;
        this.requestFrom = requestFrom;
        this.requestDate = requestDate;
        this.stationNumber = stationNumber;
        this.site = site;
        this.region = region;
        this.requestReceiver = requestReceiver;
        this.descIssue = descIssue;
        this.thirdParty = thirdParty;
        this.descResolutionAction = descResolutionAction;
        this.closerType = closerType;
        this.closeNum = closeNum;
        this.dateAction = dateAction;
        this.agentAction = agentAction;
        this.validation = validation;
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "request_number")
    public String getRequestNumber() {
        return this.requestNumber;
    }

    public void setRequestNumber(String requestNumber) {
        this.requestNumber = requestNumber;
    }

    @Column(name = "request_from")
    public String getRequestFrom() {
        return this.requestFrom;
    }

    public void setRequestFrom(String requestFrom) {
        this.requestFrom = requestFrom;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "request_date", length = 0)
    public Date getRequestDate() {
        return this.requestDate;
    }

    public void setRequestDate(Date requestDate) {
        this.requestDate = requestDate;
    }

    @Column(name = "station_number")
    public Integer getStationNumber() {
        return this.stationNumber;
    }

    public void setStationNumber(Integer stationNumber) {
        this.stationNumber = stationNumber;
    }

    @Column(name = "site")
    public String getSite() {
        return this.site;
    }

    public void setSite(String site) {
        this.site = site;
    }

    @Column(name = "region")
    public String getRegion() {
        return this.region;
    }

    public void setRegion(String region) {
        this.region = region;
    }

    @Column(name = "request _receiver")
    public String getRequestReceiver() {
        return this.requestReceiver;
    }

    public void setRequestReceiver(String requestReceiver) {
        this.requestReceiver = requestReceiver;
    }

    @Column(name = "desc_issue", length = 500)
    public String getDescIssue() {
        return this.descIssue;
    }

    public void setDescIssue(String descIssue) {
        this.descIssue = descIssue;
    }

    @Column(name = "third_party")
    public String getThirdParty() {
        return this.thirdParty;
    }

    public void setThirdParty(String thirdParty) {
        this.thirdParty = thirdParty;
    }

    @Column(name = "desc_resolution_action", length = 500)
    public String getDescResolutionAction() {
        return this.descResolutionAction;
    }

    public void setDescResolutionAction(String descResolutionAction) {
        this.descResolutionAction = descResolutionAction;
    }

    @Column(name = "closer_type")
    public String getCloserType() {
        return this.closerType;
    }

    public void setCloserType(String closerType) {
        this.closerType = closerType;
    }

    @Column(name = "close_num")
    public Integer getCloseNum() {
        return this.closeNum;
    }

    public void setCloseNum(Integer closeNum) {
        this.closeNum = closeNum;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "date_action", length = 0)
    public Date getDateAction() {
        return this.dateAction;
    }

    public void setDateAction(Date dateAction) {
        this.dateAction = dateAction;
    }

    @Column(name = "agent_action")
    public String getAgentAction() {
        return this.agentAction;
    }

    public void setAgentAction(String agentAction) {
        this.agentAction = agentAction;
    }

    @Column(name = "validation")
    public String getValidation() {
        return this.validation;
    }

    public void setValidation(String validation) {
        this.validation = validation;
    }

    @Column(name = "comment", length = 500)
    public String getComment() {
        return this.comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }
}
```

When I tried to get data in some part of my code, I got that error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:630)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:75)
    at sau.se.migration.dao.TtmpHome.findByStationName(TtmpHome.java:87)
    at sau.se.editor.dialog.StationInfo.createIncidentsTable(StationInfo.java:110)
    at sau.se.editor.dialog.StationInfo.<init>(StationInfo.java:750)
    at sau.se.editor.dialog.StationInfoAction.actionPerformed(StationInfoAction.java:19)
    at sau.se.editor.BasicGraphEditor$14.actionPerformed(BasicGraphEditor.java:1074)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2231)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:361)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1148)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:66)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as request13_21_, ttmp0_.site as site21_, ttmp0_.station_number as station15_21_' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1031)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3376)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3308)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1837)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1961)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2543)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1737)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1888)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1808)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:697)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2228)
    ... 51 more
```

I used to follow the same procedure in other entities but it is the first time I got that problem.

**UPDATE**
When using solution proposed by SpringLearner:

`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as request13_21_, ttmp0_.site as site21_, ttmp0_.station_number as station15_21_' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1031)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3376)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3308)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1837)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1961)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2543)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1737)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1888)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1808)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:697)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2228)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:361)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1148)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:66)
    at sau.se.migration.dao.TtmpHome.findByStationName(TtmpHome.java:87)
    at sau.se.editor.dialog.StationInfo.createIncidentsTable(StationInfo.java:110)
    at sau.se.editor.dialog.StationInfo.<init>(StationInfo.java:750)
    at sau.se.editor.dialog.StationInfoAction.actionPerformed(StationInfoAction.java:19)
    at sau.se.editor.BasicGraphEditor$14.actionPerformed(BasicGraphEditor.java:1074)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
14:42:38.680 [AWT-EventQueue-0] WARN  o.h.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
14:42:38.680 [AWT-EventQueue-0] ERROR o.h.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as request13_21_, ttmp0_.site as site21_, ttmp0_.station_number as station15_21_' at line 1
14:42:38.681 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - aggressively releasing JDBC connection`

Comment: perhaps if you actually provided the SQL being invoked (in the log) then people could identify what is wrong with it, and suggest a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

change     `String queryS = "select t from Ttmp t where t.stationNumber =?1";`
 to     `String queryS = "select t from Ttmp t where t.stationNumber =:stnumber ";`

and

```
query.setParameter(1, stNumber);
```

to         `query.setParameter("stnumber", stNumber);`

Comment: @HoussemBdr can you post the new stacktrace

Comment: @HoussemBdr now you have different error not the same error.You have sql syntax error now

Comment: And this is different to your orginal question.So I would suggest you to post another question

Comment: The sql syntax problem is caused by Hibernate

Answer (score 1):

I think it must be (question mark without number):

```
"select t from Ttmp t where t.stationNumber =?";
```

Comment: @HoussemBdr I don't think so, because the position is from left to right. But I would use `named parameter` instead of `positional parameter`

Comment: numbered parameters in JPQL have to have the number as the OP provides (see the JPA spec). This is not a Native (SQL) Query. Using named makes more sense though